# for same Id duplicate record with null values have to combine into one row using cte. how can we achieve in SQL server.my code is

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
with cte as (

select distinct InvoiceId
            ,case when [Action] like '%Generated%'   then ActionOn   end as InvoiceGeneratedon
            ,case when [Action] like '%PM%' then ActionOn end as pmacceptedon
            ,case when [Action] like '%Reworked%' then ActionOn end as FNAaccepted
            ,case when [Action] like '%Invoice Submitted to Customer%' then ActionOn end as submitCustomer

    from [INF_TransactionHistory]  
 ) 
    into #temp1 from cte 

    select distinct InvoiceId ,InvoiceGeneratedon,pmacceptedon,FNAaccepted ,submitCustomer
              ,DATEDIFF(day , pmacceptedon , InvoiceGeneratedon)  as DaysTakenByPM
             ,DATEDIFF(day , submitCustomer , pmacceptedon)  as DaysTakenByFNA 
             ,DATEDIFF(day , submitCustomer , InvoiceGeneratedon)  as TotalDays   from #temp1
     where InvoiceId=5401600343  
     group by InvoiceId
            ,InvoiceGeneratedon,pmacceptedon,FNAaccepted ,submitCustomer

drop table #temp1
```

Comment: Please post your source schema, data and desired output.

Comment: Try to reword your question. Why do you have to use a CTE? What's the real goal? We need data and expected output as @iamdave stated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are struggling with the CTE syntax. There is no need for a temp table. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)  for more details. It should look like:

```
with cte as (
    select columns
    from tables
)
select records
from cte
where criteria
group by columns;
```

As far as duplicates go, investigate where they are appearing. If you modify the post to select * from CTE after the CTE you can verify that they are coming from the CTE itself which I suspect is true. My best guess is that you have multiple transactions meeting the case statement criteria.

Instead of using distinct within the CTE you could look at grouping by invoice ID and then using max(case when...) or perhaps min() to make sure you get the latest date which should eliminate duplicates.

If you eliminate duplicate within the CTE it doesn't look like you will need distinct in the main query either.

It's hard to test without the full schema but I think this is roughly what you are looking for:

```
with cte as (
    select InvoiceId
            ,max(case when [Action] like '%Generated%'   then ActionOn   end) as InvoiceGeneratedon
            ,max(case when [Action] like '%PM%' then ActionOn end) as pmacceptedon
            ,max(case when [Action] like '%Reworked%' then ActionOn end) as FNAaccepted
            ,max(case when [Action] like '%Invoice Submitted to Customer%' then ActionOn end) as submitCustomer

    from [INF_TransactionHistory]  
    group by InvoiceId
 ) 
select InvoiceId ,InvoiceGeneratedon,pmacceptedon,FNAaccepted ,submitCustomer
        ,DATEDIFF(day , pmacceptedon , InvoiceGeneratedon)  as DaysTakenByPM
        ,DATEDIFF(day , submitCustomer , pmacceptedon)  as DaysTakenByFNA 
        ,DATEDIFF(day , submitCustomer , InvoiceGeneratedon)  as TotalDays
from cte
where InvoiceId=5401600343;
```